# How to rank the bars in geom_col (ggplot) from lowest to highest?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

The data below is a small subsample of my data. I plot the unemployment rate by class for each of the countries using the following code:

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x=country, y=unemployment)) + 
      geom_col(aes(fill=class))
```

It works great. However i have 30 countries and would like to rank them by order. The countries with the lowest unemployment rate for class 1 should appear first in the graph - increasing gradually to the highest unemployment rate for class 1. Is there an elegant way to do it without going through the hassle of doing it manually?

```
 country    unemployment    class
    1            20           1
    1            30           2
    1            50           3
    2            15           1
    2            30           2 
    2            55           3
    3            10           1
    3            35           2
    3            55           3
    
   structure(list(country = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3), format.stata = "%9.0g"), unemployment = structure(c(20, 30, 
50, 15, 30, 55, 10, 35, 55), format.stata = "%9.0g"), class = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: fct_reorder will do the trick but it's slightly more complicated because you want to specify class == 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of factor levels will govern how the data show up on the axis.

If the bars weren't stacked, then you could just use fct_reorder to order the factor by unemployment, but because you have multiple values per country (by class), I generated the country_order based on a filtered data frame first and then I fct_relevel 'd country by that order.

```r
df <- structure(list(country = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), format.stata = "%9.0g"), unemployment = structure(c(20, 30, 50, 15, 30, 55, 10, 35, 55), format.stata = "%9.0g"), class = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.0.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(forcats)

country_order <- df %>% 
  filter(class == 1) %>%
  mutate(country = fct_reorder(factor(country), unemployment, .desc = FALSE)) %>% 
  pull(country) %>%
  levels()

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(country = fct_relevel(factor(country), country_order))

ggplot(df2, aes(x=country, y=unemployment)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill=class))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>